# Static route in linux gets deleted automatically

Tags: linux, routes, mininet, openvswitch

I have setup a network on my computer using mininet on Ubuntu LTS 14.04.2 . I have OVS an switch with ip forwarding enabled for inter-vlan routing and I install a few policies and routes on this switch. The routes installed in different tables other than the main keep getting deleted automatically.

These are the policies I have installed.

```
0:  from all to 10.0.4.251 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.4.252 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.4.253 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.4.254 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.3.251 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.3.252 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.3.253 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.3.254 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.2.251 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.2.252 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.2.253 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.2.254 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.1.251 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.1.252 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.1.253 lookup local 
0:  from all to 10.0.1.254 lookup local 
1:  from 10.0.1.0/24 iif vlan11 lookup 2 
1:  from 10.0.2.0/24 iif vlan12 lookup 2 
1:  from 10.0.3.0/24 iif vlan13 lookup 2 
1:  from 10.0.4.0/24 iif vlan14 lookup 2 
1:  from 10.0.1.0/24 iif vlan21 lookup 3 
1:  from 10.0.2.0/24 iif vlan22 lookup 3 
1:  from 10.0.3.0/24 iif vlan23 lookup 3 
1:  from 10.0.4.0/24 iif vlan24 lookup 3 
1:  from 10.0.1.0/24 iif vlan31 lookup 4 
1:  from 10.0.2.0/24 iif vlan32 lookup 4 
1:  from 10.0.3.0/24 iif vlan33 lookup 4 
1:  from 10.0.4.0/24 iif vlan34 lookup 4 
1:  from 10.0.1.0/24 iif vlan41 lookup 5 
1:  from 10.0.2.0/24 iif vlan42 lookup 5 
1:  from 10.0.3.0/24 iif vlan43 lookup 5 
1:  from 10.0.4.0/24 iif vlan44 lookup 5 
32765:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

These are the routes installed in my main table for inter-VLAN routing

```
10.0.1.0/24 dev vlan11  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.251 
10.0.1.0/24 dev vlan21  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.252 
10.0.1.0/24 dev vlan31  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.253 
10.0.1.0/24 dev vlan41  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.254 
10.0.2.0/24 dev vlan12  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.251 
10.0.2.0/24 dev vlan22  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.252 
10.0.2.0/24 dev vlan32  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.253 
10.0.2.0/24 dev vlan42  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.254 
10.0.3.0/24 dev vlan13  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.251 
10.0.3.0/24 dev vlan23  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.252 
10.0.3.0/24 dev vlan33  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.253 
10.0.3.0/24 dev vlan43  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.254 
10.0.4.0/24 dev vlan14  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.251 
10.0.4.0/24 dev vlan24  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.252 
10.0.4.0/24 dev vlan34  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.253 
10.0.4.0/24 dev vlan44  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.254
```

These are routes for tables 2,3,4,5 respectively

```
10.0.0.0/16 dev s1-eth1  table 2  proto static  scope link 
10.0.0.0/16 dev s2-eth1  table 3  proto static  scope link 
10.0.0.0/16 dev s3-eth1  table 4  proto static  scope link 
10.0.0.0/16 dev s4-eth1  table 5  proto static  scope link
```

The issue is these routes in tables 2,3,4,5 keep getting deleted automatically within minutes of setting up. The routes in main work fine.

Link to my question on

- [network engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40569/static-route-in-linux-gets-deleted-automatically)
- [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/845431/static-route-in-linux-gets-deleted-automatically)

Please answer there, if you can't here.